# Add javascript to wp_head with call to plugin options?

Tags: plugins, wp-head

I am trying to write a plugin in wordpress and have been doing it in stages, I understand how to add javascript to the wp_head however adding multiple function calls to the plugins options is something I don't think I'm understanding. This is my first attempt at trying to write a plugin so I know I am going about this wrong. Any feedback is greatly appreciated!

If I have:

```
    function tweet_feed_it() {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".tweet").tweet({
            modpath: "path/to/plugin/twitter/",
            username: "twitter_username",
            join_text: "auto",
            count: tweet_count,
            auto_join_text_default: "We tweeted,", 
            auto_join_text_ed: "We",
            auto_join_text_ing: "We were",
            auto_join_text_reply: "We replied to",
            auto_join_text_url: "We were checking out",
            loading_text: "loading tweets..."
                    });
                 });
           </script>'};
// Add to head
add_action('wp_head', 'tweet_feed_it');
```

The script shows up in wp_head fine.

But in my wordpress plugin I have set some options and I want to call them to use within the script tags.

I will show what i have tried so you get an idea of what I am trying to accomplish at least:

```
    class TweetFeedIt {
    function tweet_feed_it() {
        function twitter_username_callback() {
            function tweet_count_callback() {
    printf( '<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".tweet").tweet({
            modpath: "http://test.phoenixlaef.com.au/wp-content/plugins/Tweet-Feed/twitter/",
            username: "twitter_username",
            join_text: "auto",
            count: tweet_count,
            auto_join_text_default: "We tweeted,", 
            auto_join_text_ed: "We",
            auto_join_text_ing: "We were",
            auto_join_text_reply: "We replied to",
            auto_join_text_url: "We were checking out",
            loading_text: "loading tweets..."
        });
    });
</script>
'
, esc_attr( $this->options['twitter_username']), esc_attr( $this->options['tweet_count'])
                );
            }
        }
    }
}
// Add to head
add_action('wp_head', 'tweet_feed_it', 'twitter_username_callback', 'tweet_count_callback');
```

Do I need to register the option settings to use it like this or is what I am trying to do just not practical?

Thanks for your help in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nesting functions in PHP very rarely makes sense. There are some advanced reason for doing it, but I doubt they are needed in this case.

```
class TweetFeedIt {
    function tweet_feed_it() {
        function twitter_username_callback() {
            function tweet_count_callback() {
                [...]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `add_action()` function can take up to 4 parameters, but those parameters are not the names of the nested functions you wrote above.

```
add_action('wp_head', 'tweet_feed_it', 'twitter_username_callback', 'tweet_count_callback');
```

Read the documentation for [PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/), for [`add_action()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action) and for [adding scripts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script). PHP does exactly what you tell it to do, but you have to follow the conventions of the language.